# In excel I am trying to create a formula the will use another cell to search for data in another workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel

here is my current formula.

```
=IF('[MC14.xlsx]Employee Training Form'!$B$21=0,"TBS",'[MC14.xlsx]Employee Training Form'!$B$21)
```

Is there a way to replace the "MC14" with a cell value "A34" to find the data I am looking for.

Comment: I am not familiar with Macros, but I think that might work better with what I am doing. is there a good site that I can get some info on macros? I need to pull from individual training records to populate our training tracker.

Answer (score 1):

Use INDIRECT:

```
=IF(INDIRECT("'["&A34&"]Employee Training Form'!$B$21")=0,"TBS",INDIRECT("'["&A34&"]Employee Training Form'!$B$21")
```

But realize there are at least two major drawbacks to INDIRECT:

1. The target workbook must be open or you will get a `#Ref` error.
2. INDIRECT is volatile and will force the formula to recalculate every time Excel recalcs.

Comment: Scott nailed it. The requirement to have the workbook referenced by indirect open is unfortunately routed in security and spreadsheet coherency. If you have direct links to workbooks, Excel can track those file links, ask the user if they wish to update the link or not, break links etc. With INDIRECT the text in the cell can really be anything and refer anywhere. If this is a problem for you, you might get around it using e.g.`INDEX(CHOOSE(MATCH(A34,{"MC14","MC15"...}), [MC14.xlsx]Sheet1!$A:$Z, [MC15.xlsx]Sheet1!$A:$Z...),21,2)` but then you'd need to list all possible filenames upfront.

Comment: Alternatively you could opt for a VBA macro, which can open a workbook, extract the cell value and close it again.